# Ps4, buying game from another account

Tags: ps4, psn

I wonder.

If I have another friends account on my ps4, and I buy a game from the ps store from his account on my ps4.

Who will pay for it? Me or him?

Answer (score 3):

Your friend will pay.

The only way to buy stuff on the PSN is either through a credit card or prepaid funds. Both are registered to your account to allow you to use them on other PlayStation consoles you may own, such as PS3, PS4, PSP, or PS Vita.

Also keep in mind that you won't be able to use whatever "you" bought if your friend's account is removed from your PS4.

Comment: I don't think this is completely true... I use PayPal on my system, so could he not just select that option and use his PayPal account to add funds to his friends wallet? Of course the friend will still own the game..

Comment: @DangerZone. Well, you could also use your own credit card to pay on a different account, but then the question would be kind of absurd.